# Compare one number in array with others in same

Tags: c#

Lets say i have an array with 10 elements in it. I want to compare the first number is it the biggest in that same array.

Is there any way to make it without linq.

Numbers are 2 4 6 7 8 9 3

I want to know if the first number is biggest or equal in array

Comment: your question is unclear. you need to better explain what you are asking, as well as posting code of what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should iterate over the array and check if there is at least one element that is bigger then the first element.

```
var array = new [] { 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 3 };

int element = array[0];
bool isBiggestOrEqual = true;
for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    if (element < array[i])
    {
        isBiggestOrEqual = false;
        break;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("Is {0} the biggest or equal to biggest in array ? {1}", element, isBiggestOrEqual);
```

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Ethan...
but to answer your question..

(not tested and not compiled => out of the head :))

```
var first = numbers[0];
foreach (var number in numbers)
{ 
   if (number > first)
       return false;
 }
 return true;
```

Comment: Isn't `first()` a Linq method?

Comment: agreed @Oluwafemi! Changed my answer

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following

```
public static bool IsFirstAMax(int[] array)
{
    if (array.Length == 0)
        return false;
    if(array.Length ==1)
        return true;
    var max = array[0];
    for(var index = 1; index  < array.Length;index++)
        if(array[index]>max)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

here a working [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/txIFtf)

Answer (score 0):

you need to loop through each number in your array , return true or false depending if your first number is the bigger in the array :

```
 bool CheckFirstNumber(int[] iArray)
    {
        bool bResult = true;
        int FirstNumber = iArray[0];

            for (int i = 1;i < iArray.Count() ;i++)
            {
                if (FirstNumber < iArray[i])
                    bResult = false;
                break;
            }
            return bResult;
    }
```

or just use link in one line of code

```
return iArray.Max() == iArray.First() ? true : false
```